# Нужна ли запятая после "поэтому"?

Tags: запятые

> Поэтому каждому в нашем коллективе доступно внутреннее и внешнее обучение.

Comment: Плюсую, shampar. Действительно, лишние повторы.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна – нет причин для постановки. Там и паузы-то нет, почему вы решили, что может быть запятая?